# Can I use tooltips in linked subplots in MPLD3

Tags: mpld3

I tried the tooltip example in MPLD3.  However, in my figure, I have several subplots with the linked x axis (length of data is the same, I am plotting different column of a dataframe).  With the code below, I was able to see the tooltip when I move the mouse in the last subplot.  However, I would like to do that when I move mouse in any subplot.  How can I achieve that?  I guess it should be sort of like the LinkedBrush example.  I just not sure how to write my plugin to handle various number of subplots.

The following code creates a figure that on the bottom subplot has the tooltip.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins, utils
N=30
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(6,10), sharex='col')
for i in range(3):
    points1=axes[i].scatter(range(N),np.random.random(size=N), color='b',marker='.')
labels0 = [ 'point {0}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(N)]
tooltip = plugins.PointLabelTooltip(points1, labels0)
plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)
mpld3.save_html(fig, 'test.html')
```

Comment: Can you add some simulated data for `sub` to make this a complete example?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry.  Just added a simple example to illustrate the question.

Comment: I suspect you want something more complicated than is achieved simply by putting `labels0 = ...` to `plugins.connect` lines in loop (as shown here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/aflaxman/453e557a69eb6b794290075065794630 )

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks Abe!  I didn't know you can put it in a loop.

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer, in case it helps others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accomplish this by putting the tooltip creation code into your loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins, utils
N=30
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(6,10), sharex='col')
for i in range(3):
    points1=axes[i].scatter(range(N),np.random.random(size=N), color='b',marker='.')
    labels0 = [ 'point {0}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(N)]
    tooltip = plugins.PointLabelTooltip(points1, labels0)
    plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)
mpld3.save_html(fig, 'test.html')
```